# add/remove class with jQuery on link select

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I'm trying to write a function in jQuery that will add a class to a selected link (which opens a page in an iframe) then remove that class when another link is selected. I received some help from another member here before for a similar type of thing, but that involved radio buttons and tables.

I tried playing with it for awhile, but jQuery is still pretty new to me so I don't know a whole lot about it.

Basically, I have about 3-4 groups of links contained in `<div id="CollapsiblePanelContent"> ... </div>` and I would like to add a style to the `<a>` tag within this container that the user selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<div id="CollapsiblePanelContent">  
  <a href="page1.asp" onclick="return handlelink(this)">Link1</a>
  <a href="page2.asp" onclick="return handlelink(this)">Link2</a>
  <a href="page3.asp" onclick="return handlelink(this)">Link3</a>
  <a href="page4.asp" onclick="return handlelink(this)">Link4</a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
    $('div').click(function(event) {
      $(this).closest('.CollapsiblePanelContent').addClass('selected').parent().siblings().each(function() {
        $(this).find('.CollapsiblePanelContent').removeClass('selected');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: is this the actual code? If so, you're missing the `<script>` tags around your javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#CollapsiblePanelContent a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload, you may remove it if don't need
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

As `CollapsiblePanelContent` is `id` so correct selector will be `#CollapsiblePanelContent` not `.CollapsiblePanelContent`.

But if you use `CollapsiblePanelContent` for multiple `div`s then instead of `id` it should be `class` with selector `.CollapsiblePanelContent`. Because multiple elements can have same `id`.

Comment: Good spot on it being an ID, rather than a class, on the `<div>` element - that's what I get for glancing at the HTML and paying attention only to the jQuery. However, the `e.preventDefault()` may interfere with any conditional logic in the `handlelink()` function to only prevent following the link in certain situations; really depends on exactly what that function does.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Your'e right, I didn't even notice i was calling for a class instead of the id (that makes prefect sense now).. I ran the function you wrote, and it does add the class to the selected link, but its not removing the class when another link is selected. Is there something else I need to add to get this to remove the class after when another link is selected? Thank you again.

Comment: Actually I just noticed its changing the class to "Current" as apposed to adding the classname "selected".. EDIT- I'm stupid, I was link to the current jQuery from the wrong url -_-. Now It's working, but it changes the class to "current selected" then when I select another link, it removes "selected" but leaves "current". Which is weird because I dont have "current" anywhere in any other code..

Comment: Also you said it would be better to use a class name as the identifier instead of the id? I do have 3 other divs with that same ID holding other links as well. I added a class to each of those and change that part of the code to `$('.dud a').on('click')`.. If I click a link in one of those divs, and then another link in the other div with the same ID then both items stay selected. Is it possible for the jQuery to remove the "selected" class from ANY links on the page or something of that nature?

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
function handlelink(this)
{
$(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
//do the rest with the click
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HTML you've provided the following should work:

```
$(function() {
    $('.CollapsiblePanelContent a').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
});
```

That binds the click event handler to any `<a>` elements inside `<div class="CollapsiblePanelContent">`, which adds the `selected` class to the clicked link, and removes the same class from all of its siblings.